# Java Network Game (might use NIO)

Tags: java, concurrency, network-programming, nio

As part of a learning experiment, I want to make a network application. I'm still learning about multithreading, and I've made a simple multithreaded "game" that involves drawing sprites on the screen, where the player can move them.

For this new project, I want to make something simple, just for the experience and learning. I want to create a server, where multiple clients can connect to it. The server will contain "game objects", which is just an object containing an x and y position, a string name, an ID to identify it, and velocity (dx and dy).

The "server" application will feature things like a worker thread updating the position of the objects (using their velocity), and it will also send the client the "state" of all game objects, so the clients can draw them for the players to see.

The clients will also send the server data whenever the player presses a button on the keyboard and generates a KeyEvent. The server will read this data and process it by updating the player's game object. For example, if the player presses the left arrow key, the client will send the server data indicating that the left key was pressed, the server will find the game object associated with the client (maybe I will store the objects in a Map like ?)

The problem is how to do this. I've never done any networking of this scale before. The most I've made so far is a buggy 2 player tic tac toe game. Since that is turn based, it is very different the application that I am now trying to make. As research, I read the entire Concurrency lesson on Oracle. I also read this tutorial on NIO. I've never used NIO before but I was recommended by multiple people to use it. I learned a lot about multithreading and concurrency from reading the code and figuring out how it works.

Since the SocketChannels communicate using ByteBuffers, one strategy I thought of is to take a List of GameObjects and serialize it to a byte array. Then create a ByteBuffer with the ByteArray and send it to the client. The client will then get all the GameObjects loaded in the server, and be able to draw all of them based on their type and states. One problem with this is that the byte array could get very large. I tested it with 256 GameObjects, and got a byte array of up to 9KB. If I compress the byte array, the size will be around 96 bytes. Still, I don't know if this is too big to be sent to the client 15 times a second.

Another option that I know of is to send the info byte by byte. For example, the first byte sent could identify what type of game object I am sending (example: cat, car, person), the next two bytes could identify the X position, then the next two the Y position, then the last byte used to identify the state of the object. Using this data, the client can just draw a sprite on the position received.

A big problem with all that I've said is that the client won't be able to interact with any of the objects. The client will just be able to send simple commands to the server, and "view" the game objects' sprites at its position. If the server wanted to tell the a game object to do a specific action, it would be hard to draw it since I will just be drawing static sprites to a screen, instead of interacting with the sprites.

I also am not sure whether or not NIO is the best idea. Most people I've talked to recommend it, but I don't quite understand the practical difference between implementing a non blocking NIO server and a multithreaded regular java.net.* server. My guess is that the non blocking server has better performance than a multithreaded one, and I would run into much less problems with just 1 thread rather than multiple threads per connection.

And finally, I've gotten mixed advice whether or not to use TCP or UDP. I've never used UDP before either. Some strongly suggest TCP, while others strongly suggest UDP.

As you can see, I am pretty unorganized and not sure on what to do. I feel like I have read a lot about networking and concurrency, and I already know enough about Swing to make graphical games. I just don't know how to put it all together.

Comment: tldr; you might want to break this up / ask more specific questions

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps consider using [Netty](https://netty.io/). I have found it extremely useful for rapid application development and fast enough for most server and client applications. You can get faster with a raw implementation of the reactor design pattern with Java NIO, but it will take a lot more work and code that is hard to debug.